# autocomplete search box and Image slider are not working at a time - jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ashx

Hello everyone I am new to jquery and i am at learning stage of jquery. My Html template already have an Image Slider and it's working fine. I have created an auto complete textbox functionality using jquery & . Now the problem is Image Slider and AutoComplete Search both are not working at a time. When I comment jquery-1.11.1.min.js, autoComplete will work but slider is not.

Here is my **Jquery for AutoComplete**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtSearchBox.ClientID%>").autocomplete('AutoCompleteLocation.ashx');
    });
</script>
```

for **FlexSlider**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#flexiselDemo").flexisel({
                visibleItems: 1,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                autoPlay: true,
                autoPlaySpeed: 1000,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                responsiveBreakpoints: {
                    portrait: {
                        changePoint: 480,
                        visibleItems: 1
                    },
                    landscape: {
                        changePoint: 640,
                        visibleItems: 1
                    },
                    tablet: {
                        changePoint: 768,
                        visibleItems: 1
                    }
                }
            });
        });
            </script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(window).load(function () {
                            $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                                visibleItems: 4,
                                animationSpeed: 1000,
                                autoPlay: true,
                                autoPlaySpeed: 3000,
                                pauseOnHover: true,
                                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                                responsiveBreakpoints: {
                                    portrait: {
                                        changePoint: 480,
                                        visibleItems: 1
                                    },
                                    landscape: {
                                        changePoint: 640,
                                        visibleItems: 2
                                    },
                                    tablet: {
                                        changePoint: 768,
                                        visibleItems: 3
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
            </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
```

**.ashx**

public class AutoCompleteSearch : IHttpHandler
    {

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Location from myLocation where " +
                "Category_Name like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(sdr["Location_Name"])
                            .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**asp.Net Control**

`<div>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchBox" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
</div>`

Please help.

Comment: Here is other queries<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zoomslider.min.js"></script>

Comment: You have the problem of loading two versions of jQuery. That is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How can I fix this??? Please help me